# "Код" музыкальных файлов

Tags: php, javascript

Я хочу попробовать создать программу для создания/редактирования какой-либо музыки. Чисто в образовательных целях я хочу узнать как работать с музыкальными файлами, изменять их, создавать...

Я знаю что есть форматы со сжатием трека и без. Например тот же .aiff, но его не открыть просто так блокнотом. Как создать собственный .aiff? Как написать в нем пару секунд звуков и получить его структуру, для изменения, изучения?

Существует MIDI. С ним все проще, зато возможностей меньше. Музыкальный диапазон ограничивает возможности, зато его можно конвертировать в MusicXML и обратно и таким образом создавать, редактировать.

Почему с тем же .mp3 так много возни? Это ведь популярный формат, в интернете должно быть очень много информации про то как его изменить, но я не нахожу ничего кроме получения тегов трека с помощью ID3(на PHP).

Как конвертировать любой формат в редактируемый код(например .XML) и обратно и что вообще можно сделать с треком?

У меня в голове путаница на этот счет, я надеюсь что тут есть человек, который объяснит как это работает.

П.С. я надеюсь работать на JS, NodeJS, PHP, если это возможно, я не собираюсь создавать крайне мощные редакторы, я хочу понять как это работает, создать через PHP какой либо небольшой(даже некрасивый) трек и все.

Comment: А как Вы себе представляете сконвертированный mp3 в MusicXML? mp3 - это грубо говоря упакованные отсчеты. А MusicXML (как и миди) - это просто записанные ноты. Но в целом, если сильно хочется с mp3 работать - с помощью ffmpeg конвертируете в pcm (raw формат). А там уже легко. А потом, после редактирования снова упаковываете.

Comment: @KoVadim в том то и дело что я себе этого даже не представляю :) Суть в том что я в принципе не понимаю как выглядит .mp3, но я предполагаю что его можно создать "вручную".

Comment: да, его можно сделать вручную. И самый простой способ - сгенерировать pcm файл и потом его сконвертировать с помощью ffmpeg.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, буду искать как это делать.

Comment: @KoVadim А, а еще, не подскажете что вы имели ввиду под "упакованные отсчеты"? Я так и не понял почему нельзя просто открыть .mp3 файл и посмотреть что внутри. А несжатые файлы типа AIFF можно как-либо прочитать? И напишите это как ответ, ибо это и будет ответом на вопрос.

Comment: я могу написать ответ, но он займет очень много места и времени. Да, похоже, что AIFF - это обычный pcm. Как прочитать? любым хекс редактором. В пхп открывайте файл как бинарный. Просто не ожидайте там текста - там просто массив байт.

Comment: @KoVadim ага, уже лучше. На счет ответа в этом ведь и суть этого портала. Кто-то напишет небольшой ответ, а через какое-то время заинтересованный человек допишет его. Но это вам решать, спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно, вот тут написано как это сделать при помощи пхп http://www.theblog.ca/merge-mp3s-php

```
<?php
// This is the class to generate mp3 files based on the anti-spam words
// Based on the PHP mp3 class at http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class
// Output code based on the FPDF class at http://www.fpdf.org
class mp3
  {
    var $str;
    var $time;
    var $frames;

    // Create a new mp3
    function mp3($path="")
    {
    if($path!="")
        {
        $this->str = file_get_contents($path);
        }
    }

  // Put an mp3 behind the first mp3
  function mergeBehind($mp3)
  {
  $this->str .= $mp3->str;
  }

  // Calculate where's the end of the sound file
  function getIdvEnd()
  {
  $strlen = strlen($this->str);
  $str = substr($this->str,($strlen-128));
  $str1 = substr($str,0,3);
  if(strtolower($str1) == strtolower('TAG'))
  {
  return $str;
  }
  else
  {
  return false;
  }
  }

  // Calculate where's the beginning of the sound file
  function getStart()
  {
  $strlen = strlen($this->str);
  for($i=0;$i<$strlen;$i++)
  {
  $v = substr($this->str,$i,1);
  $value = ord($v);
  if($value == 255)
  {
  return $i;
  }
  }
  }

  // Remove the ID3 tags
  function striptags()
  {
  //Remove start stuff...
  $newStr = '';
  $s = $start = $this->getStart();
  if($s===false)
  {
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
  $this->str = substr($this->str,$start);
  }
  //Remove end tag stuff
  $end = $this->getIdvEnd();
  if($end!==false)
  {
  $this->str = substr($this->str,0,(strlen($this->str)-129));
  }
  }

  // Display an error
  function error($msg)
  {
  //Fatal error
  die('<strong>audio file error: </strong>'.$msg);
  }


 // Send the new mp3 to the browser
  function output($path)
  {
  //Output mp3
  //Send to standard output
  if(ob_get_contents())
  $this->error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send mp3 file');
  if(php_sapi_name()!='cli')
  {
  //We send to a browser
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
  if(headers_sent())
  $this->error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send mp3 file');
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->str));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$path.'"');
  }
  echo $this->str;
  return '';
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Тут показано как соединять треки, а точнее в примере показано как соединить их в правильной очередности, но вопрос в том можно ли как-либо изменить сам трек? Открыть код трека и написать туда что либо, что бы после редактирования получился рабочий новый трек.

Comment: Тогда на ПХП нет готовых вещей того чего вы хотите. Хотел просто помочь.